# Creating the equation of a logarithmic graph given an asymptote and two intercepts

Tags: logarithms

There was a question that I came across that I was unable to answer..

> Find the equation to a logarithmic equation with an asymptote at $x=-5$
>   and containing the $X$-intercept $X=e-5$ and $Y$-intercept $Y=\log_e\dfrac{25}{e^2}$.

I understand that the basic formula of log graphs is
$$y=a\log_b(x-h)+k$$
and that given the horizontal asymptote at $x = -5$
$$y=a\log_b(x+5)+k$$

I also understand that we should be able to have two simultaneous equations:
$$e-5=a\log_b(x+5)+k$$ and $$\log_e\dfrac{25}{e^2}=a\log_b5+k$$

But I am unsure of where to go from here in order to get the full equation.

Answer (score 2):

Recall all logarithms are proportional to each other via the [change of base formula](http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm):

$$\log_b(a)=\frac{\log_c(a)}{\log_c(b)}; \quad \text{in particular } \log_b(a)=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}.$$

Therefore, you can set up the original function in the form
$$y=a\ln(x-h)+k,$$
because the coefficient $a$ in front of the natural logarithm is equivalent to switching to other bases. Now your approach is going to work.

Comment: Hey, just following up on this.
So this means that my simultaneous equations will look like:
ln(25/e2)=aln(5+k)
e−5=aln(x+5)+k
right?

Comment: @S.Ban: Close, but not exactly. In the first equation you made a typo: the right-hand side must be $a\ln(5)+k$. As for the $x$-intercept, I've just noticed (missed that when posting my original answer) that you're setting it up incorrectly. The given $x$-intercept means that the graph passes thru the point $(e-5,0)$, while you incorrectly set up something totally different.